# main isn't occuping 100%, body and html are set to 100%

Tags: css

this is my code:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#todo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#subtodo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<main id="todo">
  <div id="subtodo">
  </div>
</main>
```

I have both the html and the body set to min-height: 100%, as well as the #todo set to min 100%. Do anyone know why #todo isn't occupying the whole screen?

I have fixed it changing the min-height of #todo from 100% to 100vh, but I still don't understand why is it that it don't work with 100%.

Comment: height in `%` always means compared to the parent's element height which by default is auto (undefined). Unless you have a specific height set on the parent element it will try to calculate `100% * undefined` which also will undefined.